# Load pdf from CocoaPod

Tags: swift, pdf, cocoapods

I am trying to store pdfs in a CocoaPod (`PUIKit` - my own) and use them in a project (`FiDemo2`). While I am able to [successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7r2k.png) install the `pdf`s into `FiDemo2`.

I am not able to properly load and use them.

First I am successfully able to get the correct bundle as `"org.cocoapods.Myproject"`.

```
class This {
    static var bundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: This.self)
   }
}

var bundle: Bundle {
    return This.bundle
}
```

The blocker: when I try to run this,

```
let path = bundle.url(forResource: "add", withExtension: "pdf")
```

path is nil even though I have the correct bundle and [my pdf is in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS6vI.png). How can I load pdfs from my pod (`PUIKit`) in my project (`FiDemo2`) ?